# Java: Two jars in project with same class.

Tags: java, eclipse, class, jar, import

I have a java project that is using two imported jars with the same class (`com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder`).  Is there a way to explicitly say which jar to use when importing the class?  Using:

```
import com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder;
```

would seem to use the class in order of build path order but this does not seem to be the case for some reason causing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle()V
        at com.woodbury.GCM.HelperGmailMonitor.doEmail(HelperGmailMonitor.java:104)
        at com.woodbury.GCM.Launch.listen(Launch.java:16)
        at com.woodbury.GCM.Launch.main(Launch.java:10)
        ... 5 more
```

at runtime.  I am building the project in eclipse.

Comment: Q: Can you have two classes with the same name in different .jar's?  A: Sure.  Q: Can you rely on their position in the classpath to choose one .jar over the other?  A: No - you should disambiguate them by using qualified package names.

Comment: @paulsm4 How do I do that if they have the same fully qualified name (com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder), that is what I am looking for here.

Comment: Q: Do both .jar's each have an "IMAPFolder" with the exact same package "com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder"? If so, then I guess the two .jar's *are* incompatible.  But that's typically *not* the case...  Q: What are the two .jar files in question?  Where did they come from?  Are you *sure* you need both?

Comment: @paulsm4 mail-1.4.jar and imap.jar both have com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder and each have other packages that I need for other parts of my program but the other packages they contain are not identical so removing either would not work.

Comment: please follow my suggestion [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19341314/421195): get the JavaMail API .jar files from Oracle.  I already confirmed that the current versions of mail.jar and imap.jar at the link below do *NOT* have the conflict.  Please let us know what happens!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot do what you ask just in your Java source.  Java was not designed for that.

This is a bad situation which can only be handled reliably with custom class loaders, each providing one of the jars you need.  Since you are asking this question in the first place this is probably not the way you should go yet since that opens up a LOT of new time consuming problems.

I would strongly suggest you find out *why* you have two different versions of the same jar in your classpath and rework your program so you only need one version.

Answer (score 35):

When a class is loaded, the first implementation that matches the requested fully qualified name that is visible to the relevant `ClassLoader` is what gets returned. Any other implementations with the same fully qualified name are effectively hidden to that `ClassLoader`.

What this means in a standard Java SE application is that the first code base (e.g. a jar) listed on the classpath with the required class, provides it, and all other code bases' implementations of the same fully qualified class are hidden.

### Example:

Assume that A.jar contains the compiled class

```
package com.stackoverflow.example;
public class Hello {
     public static String getGreeting(){
         return "Hello, A!"
     }
}
```

Assume that B.jar contains the compiled class

```
package com.stackoverflow.example
public class Hello {
     public static String getGreeting(){
         return "Hello, B!"
     }
}
```

Note that in both of the above classes have the same fully qualified name.

Assume  main class is

```
   import com.stackoverflow.example.Hello;

   public class ExampleMain {
       public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println(Hello.getGreeting());
       }
   }
```

If I were to invoke my program with

`java -cp A.jar:B.jar ExampleMain`

the output is: `Hello, A!`

If I reverse the classpath like so

`java -cp B.jar:A.jar ExampleMain`

the output is: `Hello, B!`

Comment: Close, but how would you, in this scenario, say explicitly that you want to get "Hello, B!" when saying System.out.println(Hello.getGreeting()); 
in this case without explicitly stating the load order?

Comment: You'd have to put B.jar first on the classpath, so that its implementation came before any other implementations.

Comment: And how would I do that in Eclipse then, I am creating a new jar file with these two jars in it.

Comment: @Fenrir If you go to `Java Build Path` in your project properties, there should be a tab labled `Order and Export`. Simply change the order of the code bases as desired. Alternatively, you can remove one of the jars from the build path as well.

Comment: I changed the order and sadly that did not work, as stated in original post, and I cannot remove one of the jars as its other packages are needed for other functionality.

Comment: @Fenrir When you say you are creating a new jar file, are you merging the jars in to a single jar, or nesting jar files inside jar files? Specifically what feature of Eclipse are you using to do this (in either case)?

Comment: File > Export > Runnable Jar File with Library Handling = Package required libraries into generate JAR

Comment: @Fenrir I just tried the process using my examples above, created A.jar, and B.jar, added them to my build path, exported runnable jar with library and I was able to manipulate which version of the class loaded by changing the build path order and re exporting a new runnable jar. I don't know why it isn't working for you, but to debug this, you can unpack your generated jar and inspect the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file. That file contains the classpath order that will be used by that runnable jar. All the behavior of classpath ordering in my answer above should apply.

Comment: This answer wrongly implies that JAR-s are listed on the classpath, which is not necessarily the case. In fact, the classpath can contain both files and directories containing these. Therefore, if the classpath includes a directory containing several JAR-s, "the first code base (i.e. a jar) listed on the classpath with the required class"[sic] is not necessarily deterministic, and may depend on the order in which Java sorts (or not) these files.

Comment: @PhilippeCloutier It was not my intent to imply that only JARs can be code bases which is clearly not the case, I did misuse "i.e." so I've corrected that. I've never seen a non-deterministic classpath, as far as I'm aware you cloud always inspect "java.class.path" at runtime and know what the load order would be. Things get more complicated environments such as JavaEE or OSGi but those are not standard JavaSE.

Comment: I did have Java EE's web archive (WAR) files in mind. We have a WAR file with more than a hundred JAR files in WEB-INF/lib/. I do believe classpath wildcards are a Java SE 6 feature though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to fix the issue. In my scenario, I have two classes with same name and same path and eclipse always imports the wrong one. What I have done is changing the jar order in the build path and eclipse will pick the first one in the build path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE, you can set the order of exporting the files to the class loader.

I work on eclipse and I use maven. When I install the project using maven, it produced many extra jars (which i hadnt defined in my dependencies) and there was a file `org.w3c.dom.Element` which was present in 2 jar files and 3rd instance of the same file was also in JRE7.

In order to make sure the correct file is picked up, all I had to do was to go to **Java Build Path** -> **Order and Export**. Select the Jar file I wanted the classloader to give more preference and move it up with the button "Up".

This is how it looks. 
[image: Eclipse - Java Build Path -> Order and Export]
Please note that this image is for eclipse. But for other IDEs there would definitely be a similar way to work this out.

Answer (score -1):

1) In general: Yes you can have the same class in different .jar files: you just disambiguate them with a fully qualified package name.  The "Date" class (present in java.util and java.sql) is a good example.

2) If you have two *DIFFERENT* .jar files that have the *SAME* fully qualified package names ... chances are, you've got a conflict.  Even if you can hack around the InvocationTargetException by playing with the class loader, you might still encounter other problems. In this case, it sounds like maybe your two .jar files have two different implementations of the JavaMail API.  I don't know.

3) The safest bet is to satisfy all your program's references *WITHOUT* risking a conflict.  I believe if you took took the "official" .jar's from Oracle's JavaMail web page, you can do this:

https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home

'Hope that helps!

Comment: If the packages are different it is _not_ the same class.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: I agree with your answer [above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19343282/421195): "I would strongly suggest you find out why you have two different versions of the same jar in your classpath and rework your 
program so you only need one version".  Based on all the discussion, I think the OP got one JavaMail .jar from one 
place (mail.jar), and a different JavaMail .jar from a different place (imap.jar).  
STRONG SUGGESTION: The OP shold get *all* the JavaMail .jar's directly from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138643.html) => no conflict. IMHO...

Comment: He said he could not use just one (like the newest).  This needs to be resolved first before upgrading to the latest from oracle.

Comment: If the OP replaced his (mismatched) .jars with the equivalents from the Oracle page, I'll bet it would "just work".  Furthermore, I verified there is *no* package conflict between the Oracle imap.jar and mail.jar (like there is in his version).  It's definitely worth trying.  I'm just very disappointed he's probably not listening any more :(