# How do we manage 2 jars at server runtime which are having same Class

Tags: java, jar, server

I have a class called **Person** in jar **JAR-1**, and **JAR-2** 
Then how do i set to execute the Person Class from JAR-2 at runtime in tomcat web server?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these in same package as well? If yes you might have to exclude one of the jar's class.

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409190/same-class-is-in-multiple-jar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339670/java-two-jars-in-project-with-same-class could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can always write your own ClassLoader and chain it with the standard ClassLoader
    and would use the custom classloader to load from either client.dev or prod otherext .
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html